# Perimeter change when moving one point of a triangle along a circle

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I am interested in the perimeter $P(\Delta')$ of a modified version of a triangle $\Delta = (A,B,C)$. I chose point $B$ to be the point I want to shift towards the inside (or on the boundary) of $\Delta$. I chose a distance $r<h$ where $h$ is the height of the triangle. $B$ can be moved to an arbitrary point $E$ which is of distance $r$ to $B$ and lays **inside or on the boundary** of $\Delta$. This means that $E$ must also lay on the circle of radius $r$ with the center point $B$. I denote $\Delta'=(A,E,C)$. What is the perimeter $P(\Delta')$ of the new triangle given the original side lengths, $r$ (and probably some representation of the arc length to E)? In what range does $P(\Delta)-P(\Delta')$ lie in?

I attached a small figure which visualizes both triangles.

[image: Visualization of both triangles.]

## Edit

Based on the comments, I added some notation:

Assuming $B=(0,0)$, then we have $E=(x,y)$ with $x=\lambda_A x_A + \lambda_C x_C$ and $y=\lambda_A y_A + \lambda_C y_C$ ($\lambda_A+\lambda_C = 1$).

This gives us the following set of equations:

$$r=\sqrt{(0-x)^2 + (0-y)^2} = \sqrt{(\lambda_A x_A + \lambda_C x_C)^2 + (\lambda_A y_A + \lambda_C y_C)^2}$$
$$|AE| = \sqrt{(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2}$$
$$|CE| = \sqrt{(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2}$$

Moreover, we have:
$$|AB| = \sqrt{x_A^2 + y_A^2}$$
$$|CB| = \sqrt{x_C^2 + y_C^2}$$

The perimeter change is in fact the difference $|AB|+ |CB| - |AE| - |CE|$. I would like to show that $r \leq |AB|+ |CB| - |AE| - |CE|$. I struggle with the proof because I still have six variables $x_A,x_C,y_A,y_C,\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_C$.

## Background

This question arises from a computer science problem called lawn mowing/milling, where you are given a cutter (in my case a circular shape) and a Polygon to cover. I noticed that given a tour of the circular cutter one can change the cutter from a circular shape with a radius $s$ to a square with side length $2s$. Afterward, the tour can be shortened a bit. I have already proven a specific length $r$ that I can move the points of the tour "inwards" to shorten the tour. My goal is to find out how much shorter the final tour gets when I modify it. In my example, $A-B-C$ are part of the tour and $B$ is a point which can be moved inward by $r$ to a point $E$. My tour will later be $A-E-C$. I want to find out how much the tour is shortened after my transformation and I hope that it will be shortened by at least $r$.

Comment: If you know arc length(s), you know the angles $\angle ABE$ and $\angle CBE$. Then use cosine law in triangles $ABE$ and $CEB$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Yes, I can do that if I have a specific example like above. But how do I bound the difference $P(\Delta)-P(\Delta')$? My final goal is to show that $r \geq P(\Delta)-P(\Delta')$ which holds for the evenly dividing angle but might not be true for the edge cases.

Comment: Have you tried using coordinate geometry? For example, consider $B (0,0), A(-a, -b), C(c,-b)$. Point on the circle is known by the equation of the circle in terms of $r$. You can add restrictions on point $E$ as it cannot be outside $\angle ABC$.

Comment: @MathLover I have added some notation and followed your suggestion setting $B=(0,0)$. This made things a lot easier. However, I still have 6 variables.

Comment: I see at the end you say you finally want to show $r \geq |AB|+ |CB| - |AE| - |CE|$. I did not realize that was your final objective. Have you tried proving that using triangle inequality?

Comment: @MathLover I made an error in my formulation, I used $\geq$ instead of $\leq$. So I want to show $r \leq |AB| + |CB| - |AE| - |CE|$, i.e. moving the point $B$ to the inside with distance $r$ will shorten the triangles perimeter by at least $r$ (which in turn produces this inequality). Triangle inequality gives you $|AE| \leq |AB|+r$ which is not very helpful as far as I can see.

Comment: The locus of points whose distances to $A$ and $C$ sum to *exactly* $|AB|+|BC|-r$ is an ellipse with foci $A$ and $C$ and major radius $\tfrac12(|AB|+|BC|-r)$. The ellipse separates points with a larger sum from those with a smaller sum. So, the valid points $E$ on your $\bigcirc B$ are those on the circular arc(s) overlapping the interior of the ellipse. Depending upon $r$, this may-or-may-not include all points of $\bigcirc B$ overlapping the interior of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: I think that if you look at some extreme cases, you'll find that the inequality you want does not hold in general. For example, take an isosceles triangle ($f=g$) with height $h=r$ (or infinitessimally larger). With a base $j$ near zero length, the perimeter will be reduced by about $2r$, but with a longer base ($j>3r/2$) the perimeter will be reduced by less than $r$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Wouldn't a larger base result in a smaller height $h$, which in turn only allows for smaller radii? I also restrict the radius $r$ to be smaller than $h$.

Comment: @michip96 Why? Is there some relation between the base and the height that you have not told us about? For a given height value for the triangle, is there some limit on the length of the base of the triangle?

Comment: @michip96 if you take an interior point $E$ in a $\triangle ABC$, what is true is that $AB + BC + CA \gt AE + CE + BE + min (AB, BC, CA)$. Now based on how you construct $\triangle ABC$, it is not necessary that $AC$ is going to be the shortest.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I think I misunderstood you in the beginning. As far as I can tell there are no further restrictions to the triangle. I will quickly edit my answer and write about the background to my question. Anyway, I don't get why the perimeter will be reduced by less than r when the base length increases, because the side lengths $f,g$ and thus the absolute change will increase too.

Comment: @michip96 Consider a rope stretched taut between two points. You can push or pull at the middle of the rope, and be able to move it much further than the amount that the rope stretches. A longer rope will not need to stretch as much for the same amount of movement.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thank you! With the help of Blue 's visualization, I was able to get your point. I always imagined $r$ to be relatively large. But I can now see that my hope that $r$ can bound the change was wrong.

Comment: @MathLover yes, sadly I am not able to bound the length of CA.

Answer (score 1):

(Expanding a comment.)

> I would like to show that
> $$r \leq |AB|+|CB|−|AE|−|CE| \tag1$$

Without additional conditions, $(1)$ may not be true. Writing the *inequality* as
$$|AE|+|CE|\leq |AB|+|CB|-r \tag{1'}$$ leads us to consider the locus of points $P$ satisfying the corresponding *equality*:
$$|AP|+|CP|=|AB|+|CB|-r \tag2$$
This is an ellipse with foci $A$ and $C$, with major radius $\frac12(|AB|+|CB|-r)$. This ellipse separates the points with a *larger* sum from those with a *smaller* sum. The described points $E$, then, must lie on the arc where $\bigcirc B$, with radius $r$, overlaps this ellipse; depending upon $r$, this arc may-or-may-not include all (or even any!) points of the arc overlapping the triangle itself.

For instance, this first figure shows a situation with points $E_-$, $E_0$, $E_+$ on $\bigcirc B$ and inside $\triangle ABC$, but respectively inside, on, and outside the ellipse:

[image]

That is, we have
$$\begin{align}
|AE_-|+|CE_-| < |AB|+|BC|-r \quad\to\quad r < |AB|+|BC|-|AE_-|-|CE_-|\\
|AE_0\;|+|CE_0\,| = |AB|+|BC|-r \quad\to\quad r = |AB|+|BC|-|AE_0\,|-|CE_0\;|\\
|AE_+|+|CE_+| > |AB|+|BC|-r \quad\to\quad r > |AB|+|BC|-|AE_+|-|CE_+|
\end{align} \tag3$$
so that only $E_-$ and $E_0$ satisfy $(1)$.

With appropriate conditions, we can have a circumstance where the circle-triangle overlap is contained within the ellipse (which seems to be the case OP envisions):

[image]

On the other hand, we can have a case where the circle doesn't meet the ellipse at all, so all points on the circle are in the $E_+$ family that don't satisfy $(1)$:

[image]

---

For a given triangle, the threshold $r$-values that keep the circular arc within the ellipse can be determined by intersecting the circle with the ellipse. Unfortunately, conic-conic intersections like this lead to quartic equations, which are [*exceedingly* messy to solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) in general.

Unless/until OP provides additional constraints or context, this is about as far as this investigation will go.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I now get your point. Based on the visualizations you provided I imagine that the case where the interesting part of the circle is entirely within the ellipse, can only occur if the angle $\angle(A,B,C)$ and the radius $r$ is of a certain size. In my case $r \geq \sqrt{2} -1$, but as I have no bounds nor information on the side lengths of the triangle this will not be possible.

Comment: Today, I realized that I might be able to bound the perimeter of the triangle $\Delta(A,B,C)$ by a constant $C$ (which is the total length of my current tour). (In my specific case this constant is $16+8(\sqrt{2}-1)$, but I am also interested in the general case). With this information I might be able to bound $|AB|,|BC|$ to specific sizes. Do you think I have to enumerate all possible triangles with this perimeter $C$?

Answer (score 1):

This answer deals with the minimal perimeter issue.

[image]

Using slightly different notation, we have
a known $\triangle ABC$ and given radius $r_a$
of the circle $\mathcal{A}(A,r_a)$.
The circle intersects with $AB$, $AC$ at $D,\ E$, respectively.
For the point $F$ along the interior arc $DE$,
and the point $G=AF\cap BC$,
the minimal perimeter of $\triangle FBC$
is achieved when $F$ is the tangential point,
where the ellipse focused at $B,C$ touches
the circle $\mathcal{A}$, which also means
that $\angle GFB=\angle CFG=\theta$.

Let $|BF|=u,\ |CF|=v$, $|BG|=at,\ |CG|=a(1-t)$
for some $t\in(0,1)$.

Then using the cosine rule for $\triangle ABG$,
[Stewart’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)
for $\triangle FBC$ and the properties of
the bisector of $\angle CFB$, we can express $t$ in terms of
the side lengths $a,b,c$ of $\triangle ABC$ and the radius $r_a$
as the root of the quartic

\begin{align} 
q_4\,t^4+q_3\,t^3+q_2\,t^2+q_1\,t+q_0&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

where

\begin{align} 
q_4 &= (b^2-c^2)^2-4\,r_a^2\,a^2,
\\
q_3 &= 4\,c^2\,(b^2-c^2)-4\,r_a^2\,(b^2-2\,a^2-c^2),
\\
q_2 &= r_a^2\,(4\,b^2-8\,c^2-5\,a^2)+2\,c^2\,(3\,c^2-b^2),
\\
q_1 &= r_a^2\,(a^2-b^2+5\,c^2)-4\,c^4,
\\
q_0 &= c^2\,(c^2-r_a^2)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}
if the vertices $A,B,C$ in counter-clockwise orientation.

The real roots of \eqref{1} need to be checked
for which one gives the actual minimum.

For the attached image, I've got all four real roots,
two of them were greater than $1$, one gives the minimal perimeter,
and, unfortunately, another one was also in a valid range,
but the corresponding perimeter was not minimal.

Also, the curved red, green and blue lines,
shown in the image,
emanating from the vertices $A,B$ and $C$, respectively,
illustrate the corresponding locus
of the points of minimal perimeter
for possible values of $r_a,\ r_b$ and $r_c$
for the circles
$\mathcal{A}(A,r_a)$,
$\mathcal{B}(B,r_b)$
and $\mathcal{C}(C,r_c)$.

Naturally, if the angles of $\triangle ABC$ are less than $120^\circ$,
all this curves intersect at the
[Fermat–Torricelli point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point)
$T$, which provides the minimum of $|TA|+|TB|+|TC|$.

---

**Edit**

On the other hand, it is much simpler to find
the corresponding radius $r_a$ given some $t\in(0,1)$:

\begin{align}
r_a
&=
\left|
\frac{t^2 b^2-(1-t)^2\,c^2}
{(1-2t)\sqrt{(c^2-a^2\,t)(1-t)+b^2\,t}}
\right|
.
\end{align}

Note that $t=\tfrac12$ is a special (and simpler) case,
which must agree only with $b=c$,
and such condition is better considered separately.

For $b=c$, the equation \eqref{1}

factors out as

\begin{align}
(1-2t)^2(b^4-r_a^2(b^2-a^2\,t\,(1-t)))
&=0
,
\end{align}

and the proper root is $t=\tfrac12$,
so, for any valid value of $r_a$,
$G$ must be the midpoint of $BC$,
to get the minimal perimeter of $\triangle FBC$,
as expected for the isosceles $b=c$ case.

---

**Edit 2**

Actually, the valid range of $t$ would be a subset of either
$(0,\tfrac12)$ or $(\tfrac12,1)$, depending of
the side lengths $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you have put into this proof. Actually, in my specific use case, I can not decide on a specific point $F$ along the interior arc $DE$. On the other hand, your considerations of calculating the radius $r_a$ with a given $t$ might be of great interest for my problem. Imagine that I know a bound $b$ so that $b \leq r_a$. Wouldn't it be sufficient to calculate $r^i_a$ for the edge cases $t=i$, $(i=0,1)$ for which the optimal radius automatically provides me with the information that $b \leq P(ABC)-P(BFC)$ if $b \leq r^i_a$? (See Blue's answer)

Answer (score 0):

We can find perimeter change as a function of parameter $ \theta$

Let the circle be centered at (0,0) and radius r.

Let two points on a vertical  line be $ ( h,-p),(h,q) $

slant line lengths sum for $\theta_1,$ $ L1=$

$$ = \sqrt { r\cos \theta_1 -h)^2} + \sqrt{( r \sin \theta_1 +p)^2}$$
$$ + \sqrt { r\cos \theta_1 -h)^2} + \sqrt{( r \sin \theta_1-q)^2}$$
For $\theta_2$, $L_2=$
$$ = \sqrt { (r\cos \theta_2 -h)^2} + \sqrt{( r \sin \theta_2 +p)^2}$$
$$ + \sqrt { (r\cos \theta_2 -h)^2} + \sqrt{( r \sin \theta_2-q)^2}$$

[image]

The perimeter change is  difference  $ L_2- L_1$ where $L_2$ pair is marked in red. It depends on two $\theta_ s$ , the constants are  $( h,p,q,r).$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you specify which angles are $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

Comment: When you are moving from one point to another on a circle you already know their fixed  station $\theta_s$, in polar coordinates right?

Comment: In my problem, I have a triangle $\Delta((0,0),(h,-p),(h,q))$ and move the point $(0,0)$ to a point $(x,y)$ on the circle so that $(x,y)$ lies in the interior or on the boundary of the original triangle. I can only provide you with an angle or arc length $\angle((h,q),(0,0), (x,y))$

Comment: Please make a sketch including the new position. Several things get cleared up.

Comment: I did but an example in my question where $\Delta(A,B,C)$ is the original triangle and $\Delta(A,E,C)$ is the modified triangle. In your case, $B=(0,0)$ and the situation is viewed from a 90-degree angle.